# Post variable when link is clicked from link menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 link i menu. And I post their ID when link is clicked:

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/cLGP5/)

html:

```
            <div class="home-content">
                <div class="menu-bar">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                          <li class="active" id="top_picks"><a href="#">Top Picks<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" id="popular">Popular<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" id="analysis">Friends analysis</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="custom-alert">Article changes everyday! come back for more fun......</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="articleContent">This content changes when link is clicked</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu-bar li a").click(function () {
        var category = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        //$('label').css('color', selText);
        // When user clicks o "top picks" then it does not post category to ivite_db.php
            $.ajax({
                    url: "invite_db.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"link_menu": category},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".articleContent").html(data);
                    }
                });           
        });
    });
```

code works fine when `popular` and `analysis` link is clicked. But when `top_picks` link is clicked, it does ot post the category?

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5):

You should have the ID in the `a` element, not the `li`, try this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#" id="top_picks">
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgtrK/)